# Does Fjällräven produce serious outdoors gear, or is it just trendy?

Tags: gear

I noticed that there is a lot of (quite expensive) Fjällräven outdoors gear for sale here in Germany and am curious whether this is a brand worth looking into, or whether their products are more trendy than practical.  Is Fjällräven a reputable supplier of serious outdoors gear?

Comment: This is subjective and not a good fit for Stack Exchange.

Comment: I think this question can be salvaged. It should ask: "When shopping for outdoor clothing, how can I tell if something is suitable or is just intended to look trendy". (Since you're from Germany, stay away from Jack Wolfskin. That's my personal biased opinion :D )

Comment: Their down parka seems serious and legit, not sure about the rest of the stuff.

Comment: Jack Wolfskin does have some good items for a fair price. I would consider it a mid-tier brand.

Answer (score 4):

Fjällräven is a solid decades old brand.

However, it may be considered very trendy and therefore be over priced in Germany. You should check the prices on Swedish net sites.